# Element-wise comparison of vector and scalar fails in rpy2 with Python 3

Tags: python, r, python-3.x, numpy, rpy2

It looks like rpy2 doesn't behave exactly the same in Python3 and Python2. In particular, in Python 2.7.x, I am able to compare a [Vector](http://rpy2.readthedocs.io/en/version_2.8.x/vector.html) with a scalar, whereas in Python 3.5.x, if I try to do that, the following error is raised:

```
TypeError: unorderable types: IntVector() > int()
```

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
>>> from rpy2 import robjects
>>> x = robjects.IntVector([5, -1])
>>> x > 0
```

And here is an extract of my `pip freeze` (same in both environments):

```
rpy2==2.8.2
numpy==1.11.1
```

I would like to understand if it's a bug in rpy2 or simply a different behaviour of some library that rpy2 relies on (numpy for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a bug, I would think that it was with Python 2.

An R vector is a sequence and the default Python behavior does not make such comparisons possible. For example:

```
>>> [1,2,3] < 2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-f7a2f4fe21e0> in <module>()
----> 1 [1,2,3] < 2

TypeError: unorderable types: list() < int()
```

On the other hand, R's vectorized counterpart can be called throught the delegator `.ro` (as in "R Operator"). See https://rpy2.readthedocs.io/en/version_2.8.x/vector.html#operators

```
>>> v = IntVector([1,2,3])
>>> v.ro < 2 
R object with classes: ('logical',) mapped to:
<BoolVector - Python:0x7fc7789a5a08 / R:0x22d25f8>
[       1,        0,        0]
```

Comment: You're right, it has nothing to do with rpy2. Thanks for your answer!